# How to fetch newest comments to any instagram post in the account?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, endpoint

We're developing a service which helps owners of social accounts to answer questions asked in their social accounts/communities. The issue we're having with Instagram is the following: we obviously have read the open info on endpoints and comments and we do the following: we snatch some X top media of the account, and then fetch the comments from each media to see if there is a new comment there. It works, but.

We have to limit ourselves to certain number of top media to track. If there is an active account, it can easily have 1000s of posts. Ok, the probability of someone commenting on media like #900 is fairly low but still requesting and snatching comments for 1000s of posts seems like just creating unnecessary entropy :) and unnecessary load to server and to instagram too.

We're very sure there should be some way/hidden/secret/private/unofficial endpoint or whatever which gives out just the latest comments regardless of how deep the commented media is in the account.

If anyone knows how to do it, please share. I'd be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Keep a track of comment count for all posts, and check for the count via `media/recent API` every hour or so, and then fetch comments using the `get comments API` for the media that has changed comment count.

`media/recent API` can be used to get comment count for up to 32 posts with one API call, so this will not reach the API rate limits quickly. This is better than using `get comments API` for every post to see if there is new comment.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?count-32&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

API response will have comment count:

```
"data": [{
        "comments": {
            "count": 0
        },
        ...
        "id": "xxxx",
        ...
```

if count has changed the use the `id` to get comments:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, we actually thought about it, but thought that it is fairly common situation (at least in the accounts we looked at) when there are some spam/inappropriate comments which the account owner may want to delete, while the new will appear and it will mess the comments count. However, thanks again, we'd need to think about it again.